# Enabling and Configuring MS DTC on Windows Server Core machines

Tags: sql-server, transactions, windows-server, msdtc, server-core

Since we do distributed transactions using Entity framework, we currently have DTC enabled on both the client/server and the SQL server boxes in all environments.

This was easy to set up using using [How to Enable MSDTC on a Web Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx) and it works well.

However our production environment's use Windows Server Core and this is a rudimentary command line based environment.

How do I enable/configure MS DTC on the Windows Server Core machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From another computer**, you can:

- run `Dcomcnfg.exe`
- rigth click on Console Root / Component Services / Computer
- select New / Computer
- add your server

**Powershell**

From Server Core Powershell window or using a remote Powershell session you can use MS DTC cmdlets: [Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn464259%28v=wps.630%29.aspx)

You have to figure out which one are needed based on your requierement.

You can for example use [Set-DtcNetworkSetting](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dn464230%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) in order to modify network and security configuration for a DTC instance.

Comment: for PS `Get-DtcNetworkSetting`   and `Set-DtcNetworkSetting -XATransactionsEnabled $True -Confirm:$False
Stop-Dtc
Start-Dtc`